# Showing children links from a custom menu in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm new to Drupal so bear with me. I'm using the Omega theme (http://drupal.org/project/omega) and created a custom menu to use as the main menu. In the template I'm using this to get and display the menu:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-omega-main-menu'), 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu'))));?>
```

When I go to view the site, the menu shows, however the children menu links do not get rendered. I also attempted this:

```
<?php print theme('links', array('links' => menu_navigation_links('menu-omega-main-menu',1), 'attributes' => array('id' => 'main-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix', 'main-menu'))));?>
```

to try to set the level depth the menus are rendered but then doesn't show at all.

To the first question that most people will try to ask, yes I have 'Show as expanded' checked.

Comment: The second natural question is: have you set your custom menu as the source of secondary menus?